# Multilanguage URLs

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, uri

In codeigniter, the name of your controller, reflects the URL.
But my question is, how can you create multi language URLs without copy/pasting all your controllers.

Example:

- In english the URL would be:  http://www.example.com/order
- In dutch the URL would be: http://www.example.com/bestellen
  ("bestellen" is dutch for "order")

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Isn't it something you can do with simple htaccess redirection?

Comment: Wouldn't you risk collisions? Quite a few languages are similar, and you would end up with two controllers by the same name but for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [URI routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in Code Igniter's user guide.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a **URL rewrite filter** is used to handle this kind of behaviour.

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter but a quick Google search shows this page about using [mod rewrite](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by creating aliases to each controller. Check your config/routes.php path